# Elasticsearch / Logstash: Get ASN number from geoip plugin

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, geoip

I am using the `geoip` plugin to get geo location information as follows:

`geoip { source => "clientIP" }`

According to the official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-geoip.html#plugins-filters-geoip-default_database_type), if I want to get `ASN` information I have to change the database type to `ASN`

My question is whether it is possible to have both `ASN` **and** coordinates information, since I want to be able at the same time to have Kibana [visualizations](https://www.elastic.co/blog/geoip-in-the-elastic-stack) (which needs the coordinates).

**edit**: currently I am trying to get first the `asn` as follows:

```
   geoip {
    default_database_type => "ASN" 
    source => "dst" 
   }

   mutate {
     add_field => [ "[dst_asn]", "%{[geoip.asn]}" ]
     # remove_field => [ "geoip" ]      
   }
```

but for some reason the `dst_asn` I am getting has this value  (i.e. replacement does not work)

```
#  dst_port         443
?  geoip.as_org           Dropbox, Inc.
?  geoip.asn              19679
```

despite the fact that `geoip.asn` exists;

Comment: Can you choose both database types and create to fields? One for coordinates and one for ASN ?

Comment: @HauLuk pls check my relevant edit

Comment: I'm not sure about geoip. It looks like the ASN and coordinates from in different datatabase files. So you might need to query twice for the information. I know IP2Location Logstash supports ISP name and coordinates query in one single query. You can find the library in Github.